initialize an unordered_set as a static member variable vs initialize in a constructor in C++
Trying to understand which is more efficient.

Initialize unordered_set member variable as a static member variable
Initialize unordered_set member variable in the constructor

Is one better than the other in terms of less memory usage?
class Example
{
 private:
  enum Names
  {
   JOHN = 0,
   MIKE,
   CHARLIE,
   TOM
  };
  static unordered_set<Names> checkNames_v1;
  unordered_set<Names> checkNames_v2;

 public:
   // Constructor
   Example()
   {
    checkNames_v2.insert(JOHN);
    checkNames_v2.insert(MIKE);
   };
};

unordered_set<Names>Example::checkNames_v1
{
  JOHN,
  MIKE
};


It depends. What is the problem that the set should solve? Do you need only one single and shared set throughout the life-time of the program, no matter how many objects you create? Or will each object need their own unique set?

It is more about the semantics of your program than about optimization.

The main difference between static members and other (regular) members in class is that static ones will be intialized exactly once and thus whenever you assess this static member from any object, you are accessing the same static set. Unlike static members, the ordinary data members are initialized every time a new object of the class is created. So, you have different set for every different object. This has nothing to do with optimization and is on need basis...

You just can't compare a static and non-static member that way directly. They're designed for different purposes. And have different use cases and need for existence.

"Is one better than the other in terms of less memory usage?" - if you need only one such map in your program, but you have multiple Example objects - then the static one will potentially consume less memory, since it is not stored per Example object.

As noted in comments, static exists for a specific purpose, and memory usage considerations should not tell you whether to use static.
If all your Example objects need to use the same set, you have to use static. If each of your Example objects needs to use its own set, you should not use static.
A corner case exists, where you will have only one Example object (a singleton). In this case, don't use static — it will have the same memory usage, but clearer code.
If you don't even care whether all your objects will share the same set or have one of their own, then yes, static will ensure your program has only one set, and this will save memory. In this case, you don't care whether your program does the right thing, so a bit hard to consider this case seriously.

If there is only one Example object (singleton) then yeah it makes sense not to use “static” and initialize it in the constructor. That’s a good point.
